# UsingWebBrowser control in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, browser, thumbnails

I want to create site thumbnails through my web application, so I thought I would use the WebBrowser control. However, I get an error:

> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

I tried setting the current thread:

`Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA`

But that didn't help.

Is in not possible to use the WebBrowser control in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, you can use it, it's a little more complicated than setting AspCompat="true",  see if this helps

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Get-Web-Site-Thumbnail-Image.aspx