# GET web browser control sources using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How do I get the source of another web site using the `WebBrowser()` control in an asp.net code behind page.

so far I have this but dont have any options to navagate or the set cookies or to get the page loaded source? can you please help?

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim a As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser()
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    'get the source

End Class
```

And I get this error

> ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be
>   instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded
>   apartment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem using winforms WebBrowser in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461420/problem-using-winforms-webbrowser-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work perfectly

we need to add webbrowser with threading other wise we will get ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment. error

this is the way we can make webbrowser work in asp.net webpages

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CustomBrowser
/// </summary>
public class CustomBrowser
{
    public CustomBrowser()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    protected string _url;
    string html = "";
    public string GetWebpage(string url)
    {
        _url = url;
        // WebBrowser is an ActiveX control that must be run in a
        // single-threaded apartment so create a thread to create the
        // control and generate the thumbnail
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetWebPageWorker));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        string s = html;
        return s;
    }

    protected void GetWebPageWorker()
    {
        using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
        {
            //  browser.ClientSize = new Size(_width, _height);
            browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            browser.Navigate(_url);

            // Wait for control to load page
            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                Application.DoEvents();

            html = browser.DocumentText;

        }
    }

}
```

in webpage

```
CustomBrowser browser = new CustomBrowser();
string s = browser.GetWebpage("http://localhost:8781/WebSite3/Default3.aspx");
Response.Write(s);
```

Comment: I've got the code "running" but Print() and ShowPrintDialog() does nothing. No exceptions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is slightly unorthodox in ASP.NET, but here is an example that may help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

I had found the same error, when I used webBrowser object in asp.net page.
But after I found that solution,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1054408/900284

Now it is fine.